# ¿Cómo generar código alfanumerico en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mvc

Necesito que se me genere un código alfanumerico al hacer un submit y sea insertado en un campo "Código verificación.

El Código serviría para que el usuario pueda verificar el estado de su solicitud, como funciona en las páginas de solicitud de visado, te dan dos códigos que te sirven de tracking para ver el estado de tu solicitud.

He buscado en la web, pero no termino de entender mucho o simplemente no es lo que ando buscando.

Espero logren ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Que cosas no terminas de entender o que intentaste que no sirvio? lo que pedis es simplemente generar una cadena usando random. intentaste algo?

Comment: Una cadena random, de momento lo que he visto creo se puede implementar, el problema es que no sabría como, lo que he visto ha sido en Windows Form

Comment: Yo cree una vez hace un tiempo una pequeña pagina que tenía recuperación de contraseña y para eso generaba un código random de 6 caracteres, fue hecho con regex. No se si buscas algo como eso.

Answer (score 2):

Estás buscando un GUID. Los GUIDs se generan automáticamente y garantizan ser únicos, aunque no puedes cambiar su formato. Realmente no son únicos 100%, pero es muy muy muy poco probable que se generen dos GUIDs iguales. Hay mucha documentación escrita al respecto, por si quieres informarte más sobre el tema.

```
var code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Esto te devuelve una cadena con el formato xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Si quieres quitar los guiones, simplemente haz un replace.

```
code = code.Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que me sirve, pero de quere hacer el codigo mas corto, es posible?

Comment: Te dejo un enlace con varias propuestas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458468/youtube-like-guid